# Android socket connection to Python server

Tags: android, python, sockets

all
I've created simple android app which should connect to Python 3.6 server through socket and send data. It doesn't work. I've lost my mind checking what's not working. Could You help me?

Main Activity

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity  {
public Button but1;
int Ra;
public void init(){
    but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Client Connection = new Client();
          Connection.execute();


        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},Ra);
    init();
}}
```

Second file

```
public  class Client extends AsyncTask<Void ,Void , Void > {


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
{
    final String adress = "192.168.1.3";
    final int Port = 70;
    Log.d("Connection","trying to create connection");
            try {
                Log.d("Connection", "Creating socket");
                Socket connect = new Socket(adress, Port);
                Log.d("Connection","Connected");
                DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
                DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
                dout.writeUTF("Hello");
                dout.flush();
                Log.d("Connection","Sent");
                dout.close();
                din.close();
                connect.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("connection",e.getMessage());
            }}
            return null;
}}
```

Python server

```
    import socket

_Connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#Creating socket
#binding socket to port
_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 70)
print('Starting Server on {} port {}'.format(*_ADDRESS))

_Connection.bind(_ADDRESS)

_Connection.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = _Connection.accept()
    print("Connection from ", addr)
    msg = _Connection.recv(1024)
    print(msg)
```

Log

> 08-24 17:31:43.950 32614-1203/com.example.marcin.tcpiptest D/connection: failed to connect to /192.168.1.3 (port 70) from /:: (port 47696): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

if anybody knows, what does I'm doing wrong and they would tell me, I would be grateful

Comment: Not working is not a good error description. Any errors? Exceptions? Crashes. Tell us what happens and not happens.

Comment: Where does your app run?

Comment: I would, but nothing happens. 
Server is not finding out any connections.

Comment: I asked about the client. Which logs do you see?

Comment: @greenapps First time my app was running on android virtual device from Android Studio, but I find out that this could be the problem. Then I've installed app on my phone which was connected to my WiFi and nothing happen again.

Comment: `catch (IOException e){}` An empty catch blok! That is pretty bad. Add the normal e.printStackTrace(); and log e.getMessage().

Comment: Nothing happens? You have so many log statements in your client. Tell which ones you see.

Comment: `_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 70)`. I would not bind a server to localhost as then connections from outside device/pc are not accepted.

Comment: @greenapps 
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/24fr <-- Logs

Comment: Please post your logs as text in your post.

Comment: @greenapps Logs are too big to copy-paste them to my post.

Comment: nvm I've got important Log. 
connection Timeout after 3 minutes from app start

Comment: You should only post some relevant lines. Starting with this one:     Log.d("Connection","trying to create connection");

Comment: Set the timeout to three seconds. Then you can test quicker.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you. The problem was on python server.

Comment: Yes. It was bound to localhost. You could confirm that.

Answer (score -1):

```
msg = _Connection.recv(1024)
```

Change server to

```
msg = _Connection.recv(0)
```

Is a buffer problem, I have same. Try:

```
msg = _Connection.recv(10)
```

And send message from Android to server "1234567890server"

The server only show "server".

Comment: Python server

    import socket

_Connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#Creating socket
_port=1234
_ADDRESS = "" //any from localhost
print('Starting Server on {} port {}'.format(*_ADDRESS))

_Connection.bind(_ADDRESS,_port)

_Connection.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = _Connection.accept()
    print("Connection from ", addr)
    msg = _Connection.recv(10)
    print(msg)